# Visual Studio Profile: Source Information is not availabe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiler

I was trying to profile a software I'm working on but the function names didn't get resolved. I did a Hello world simple software and the profile doesn't work there as well.

I tired all debug information formats:
[image]

/DEBUG is also set:
[image]

a .pdb file exits next to the empty.exe along with an empty.dll. I also added the .pdb directory to the debug source files.
[image]

But no functions show up. Instead I get a "Source information is not available."
[image]

All I have is a main.cpp with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    float number = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
            number = number + number / i;
        }
    }

    printf("%lu ", number );
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my build output:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: empty, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>Generating code
1>Previous IPDB not found, fall back to full compilation.
1>All 1 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
1>Finished generating code
1>empty.vcxproj -> C:\Users\abaghdad\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\empty\x64\Release\empty.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 6:30 PM and took 00.753 seconds ==========
```

I'm on Visual Studio 2022. Version 17.5.3

Comment: What happens when you launch the debugger?  Can you step through the source code then? _I also added the .pdb directory to the debug source files._ this should not be necessary.

Comment: The debuger works fine (in debug mode), and shows the correct call stack with the line numbers and everything. Something to note is that the debuger has empty.exe! main() in the call stack while the profile has empty.dll

Answer (score 1):

It took some time but it turns out the problem came from importing my VS settings from another workstation. Apparently, VS copies Cache symbol path also, why though?

Anyways, to fix it, just go to Tools>Options. Then in Debugging>Symbols add a valid and accessible path to the "Cache symbols in this directory".

[image]